# JQuery Hide Not Working In Chrome

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of radio buttons on a screen, with a dropdown that appears when one of them is selected:

```
<div class="sectionContent">
    <input type="radio" value="Parts" name="Order.OrderType" @if(Model.Order.OrderType=="Parts" ){ <text>checked</text>} />Parts Order
    <br /> <span id="TieToJob">
                    <table>
                        <tr><td style="width:150px">Job</td><td>@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.Order.JobID, new SelectList(ViewBag.ActiveJobs, "Value", "Text", Model.Order.JobID), "## Please Select ##")</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </span>

    <input type="radio" value="Stock" name="Order.OrderType" @if(Model.Order.OrderType=="Stock" ){ <text>checked</text>} />Stock Order
    <br />
</div>
```

I then have some Jquery script to hide the SPAN when the "Stock Order" option is selected:

```
$('input[name=Order.OrderType]').click(function () {
        if ($('input[name=Order.OrderType]:checked').val() == "Parts") {
            $("#TieToJob").show("slow");
        }
        else {
            $("#TieToJob").hide("slow");
        }
    });
```

the above code works fine when changing between Stock/Parts.

However, if the user is editing an existing stock record, then I want the dropdown to be hidden by default. I am using the following code to do so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('input[name=Order.OrderType]:checked').val() == "Parts") {
        $("#TieToJob").show("slow");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#TieToJob").hide("slow");
    }
});
```

This seems to work fine in IE, but not in chrome - the "Stock" radio is selected, but the dropdown wont hide on page load (changing to parts, then back again will hide it). I've tried putting an Alert() in the else statement, and this is being displayed, just the SPAN wont hide!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` in the name of the field. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('input[name=Order\\.OrderType]:checked').val() == "Parts") {
        $("#TieToJob").show("slow");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#TieToJob").hide("slow");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use quotes around the attribute value:

```
if ($('input[name="Order.OrderType"]:checked').val() == "Parts") {
    // code...
}
```

Comment: The if statement appears to be working correctly as it is - if I put an `alert()` in the else clause, it does fire as expected - it's just the `$("#TieToJob").hide("slow");` which doesn't work on page load in Chrome only.

Comment: @GavinCoates Ah, I understand. I would imagine that it because it is invalid to have a block level element (`table`) inside a inline element (`span`). If you change the `#TieToJob` element to a `div` it should work. If you need to maintain the inline layout, set `display: inline-block` on it using CSS.

Comment: yep, changing it to a DIV fixed it. Strange that it works fine when changing between radio buttons, but not on page load!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the `.` character like:

```
$('input[name=Order\\.OrderType]')
```

Else in chrome you will get the error like:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=Order.OrderType]:checked

Comment: no errors are being received in the chrome console, and the IF statement does seem to be working, it's just the `$("#TieToJob").hide("slow");` which doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=Order.OrderType]:checked').val() == "Parts")
```

This function return only first checked value. So when you have checked Parts and user check Stock it wasnt run.

You shall first load all checked input and by for loop check value of each them.